# Describe type of curried state handler with React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, type-inference

I'm trying to describe the type of the function which handles change event to reflect the value in the state.

The desired implementation would look like:

```
handleChange: ChangeHandler<State> = field => value =>
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
```

Given state:

```
interface State {
  title: string;
  description: string | null;
}
```

One could pass this function to the component as:

```
<TextComponent onChange={this.handleChange('title')} />
```

My best attempt to tackle this problem was to create the following type:

```
type ChangeHandler<S> = <K extends keyof S, V extends S[K]>(key: K) => (value: V) => void;
```

However, this seems to work only if all properties of the state are optional. I can't manage to get this to work with state of both optional and non-optional properties.

Compiler error:

> [ts] Argument of type '{ [x: string]: V; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'State | ((prevState: Readonly, props:
>   Readonly) => State |
>   Pick | null) | Pick<...> | null'.
>   Type '{ [x: string]: V; }' is missing the following properties from
>   type 'Pick': title, description [2345]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Root Cause

This is caused by a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) with TypeScript, where computed property names consisting of a **union of literals** are widened.

In `handleChange`, the type of `field` is widened from `'title' | 'description'` to `string`, which causes `this.setState` to fail due to the way `this.setState`'s typings are defined.

Below is a simplified definition of `setState`:

```js
function setState<K extends keyof State>(s: Pick<State, K>): void {
    console.log(s);
}
```

When applying that definition to `handleChange`, the `K` above becomes `'title' | 'description'`, and the `s` parameter becomes `Pick<State, 'title' | 'description'>`, which is essentially equivalent to the `State` interface.

So, given that our `field` has been widened to `string` and `this.setState` in this context accepts `State`, we'll get the error you're seeing as we are calling `this.setState` with the following type:

```
{ [x: string]: V }
```

Which is not assignable to `State` as it's missing the required parameters `title` and `description`.

### Solution

Our best bet here is to use a **type assertion** to silence the error while maintaining type checking. The updated definition is below:

```
let handleChange: ChangeHandler<State> = field => value =>
    setState({ [field]: value } as unknown as State);

let x = handleChange('title');

x('test'); // OK

x(50); // Error: should be string
```

See [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ChangeHandler%3CS%3E%20%3D%20%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20S%3E(field%3A%20K)%20%3D%3E%20%3CV%20extends%20S%5BK%5D%3E(value%3A%20V)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20State%20%7B%0A%20%20title%3A%20string%20%7C%20boolean%3B%0A%20%20description%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20setState%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20State%3E(s%3A%20Pick%3CState%2C%20K%3E)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(s)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AsetState(%7B%20title%3A%20''%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%20when%20called%20directly%0A%0Alet%20handleChange%3A%20ChangeHandler%3CState%3E%20%3D%20field%20%3D%3E%20value%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20setState(%7B%20%5Bfield%5D%3A%20value%20%7D%20as%20unknown%20as%20State)%3B%0A%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20handleChange('title')%3B%0A%0Ax(true)%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0Ax('')%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0Ax(50)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20should%20string%20%7C%20boolean) containing the code above.

---

See [discussion](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635) on this specific issue on DefinitelyTyped for alternate solutions / approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You must not define `V extends S[K]` as you can directly inline this declaration as follows:

```
type ChangeHandler<S> = <K extends keyof S>(key: K) => (value: S[K]) => void;
```